# php xam error paginador

Tags: php, xampp

intento hacer un paginador, pero me sale este error y la verdad no encuentro el problema

> error: Advertencia : Variable no definida $conexión en
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Facturacion\sistema\buscar_cliente.php en la línea 53
>
> Error fatal : TypeError no detectado: mysqli_query(): Argumento #1
> ($mysql) debe ser de tipo mysqli, nulo dado en
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Facturacion\sistema\buscar_cliente.php:58 Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Facturacion\sistema\buscar_cliente.php(58): mysqli_query(NULL, 'SELECT COUNT(*). ..') #1 {main} lanzado en
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Facturacion\sistema\buscar_cliente.php en la línea 58

código:

```
//paginador//

53  $sql_registe = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_registro FROM cliente 
    WHERE (idcliente LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR
    Nit LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR 
    Nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR 
    Telefono LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR 
58  Direccion LIKE '%$busqueda%' ) and estatus = 1 ");

    $result_register = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_registe);
    $total_registro = $result_register['total_registro'];
```

Comment: Quita los paréntesis que engloban los OR y dime que sale, también debes verificar por si el select no encuentra algún registro con dicha condición.

Comment: Al parecer el navegador o algo está traduciendo de manera automática los errores que normalmente salen en inglés y por eso te muestra una variable `$conexión` que no existe. En su lugar debes concentrarte en la variable `$conection` que si está en la línea 53. ¿Estás seguro que estás importando los archivos de conexión a la base de datos? o ¿Estás seteando la  variable `$conection` en el mismo archivo previamente?